# Can't boot in windows 8 after installing lubuntu and running boot-repair

Tags: windows-8, mount, grub

I installed lubuntu to a flash drive on my windows machine. Because the boot manager wouldn't find the usb I ran boot-repair. Now Grub can't find Windows 8. To make matters worse I can't mount my hard drive to recover data because it gives the error:

Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/lubuntu/B85EA41D5EA3D284: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda4" "/media/lubuntu/B85EA41D5EA3D284"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

The file created by Boot-Repair can be found at http://www.garypickrell.info/boot.txt

Q1) What can I do to recover? Q2) How can a prevent this from happening in the future? I was tempted to disconnect the hard drive but that required disassembling most of my laptop.

Comment: I would use the `Windows Recovery Console` to repair the Windows Bootloader.  **Because you shouldn't have had to install grub if you installed it to a flash drive.**

Comment: Ramhound, thanks!  It looks like the Windows Recovery Console is the way to go.  I've found I can get into it via F11.  What is the safest way to use it and not loose data?